# AngularJS - filtering hours from a JSON date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a variable in which I stored a date retrieved from the server. It looks something like this:

```
"draw_start_at": "2015-09-04T08:54:09.574Z"
```

I would like to just extract hours and minutes from here.

Comment: And what have you try so far ? What is your problem ?

Comment: `{{currentdate | date}}` and `{{currentdate | 'hh:mm'}}`, no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LimitTo**

Using `limitTo`you can take your full string and just display some characters from it. Take a look at the full documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

**HTML**

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

**JS**

```
$filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin)
```

**Conclusion**

This lets you specify a begining and end for the characters you wish to display, you can cut out all of the other things around and just be left with the hours.

Comment: Useful approach. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
{{draw_start_at | date: 'hh:mm'}}
```

Comment: of course that's the obvious solution. Problem is, it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: it works in my project. why don't you show more of your code?